# Bootstrap tab content won't open after clicking tab link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

Code looks fine in my opinion, I basically used the example code from the docs. jQuery is also referenced before bootstrap.js as well. What could be the issue here? When I click on any other tab that's not active, it still only displays the first tabs content.

```
     <section id="how-it-works">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="wizard">
           <div class="wizard-inner">
            <div class="connecting-line"></div>
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab4" role="tab" title="That's It!">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="#tab1" role="tabpanel">
                <h3>Step 1</h3>
                <p>This is step 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab2" role="tabpanel">
                <h3>Step 2</h3>
                <p>This is step 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab3" role="tabpanel">
                <h3>Step 3</h3>
                <p>This is step 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="#tab4" role="tabpanel">
                <h3>Step 4</h3>
                <p>That's It!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `#` in the ID of each tab under tab content.

```
id="#tab4" to id="tab4"
```

Also, you tagged bootstrap 3 but the code you are using looks like it is from bootstrap 4.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I am actually using an older version of Bootstrap, version 3.1.1 to be exact. I removed the # but still no luck. I click on the tab and it does nothing. So frustrating.

Comment: After removing the # from the ID, im able to navigate the tabs and they become active, but they dont show the content for that tab, its like stuck on the content for the first tab.

Comment: I don't see a Carousel in the 3.1.1 documentation. Where did you get the code from? Because it looks like bootstrap 4 code which won't work in 3.